# Hypercentral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group such that every chief factor is central.
Is $G$ [hypercentral](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Hypercentral_group)?

I was thinking that if you refine $1\leq G$ to a principal series, that it is also a central one. Can we say from this that $G$ is hypercentral?